# Is it possible to have a form built by a user?

Tags: python, django

For example:

I have a user that wants to create a contact form for their personal website. They want three `input type=text` and one `textarea` and they specify a label and an name/id for them on my site. Then they can use this form on their site, but I will handle it on mine?

Is it possible for django to spit out custom forms specified by the user?

Edit: If django is too "locked down" what would you recommend I do? I would like to stay with python.

Comment: Is this what you mean? You want a user to go to yoursite.com and input some kind of form specification. yoursite.com then spits out some HTML for a form that they put on their own webpage. That form has `action=` pointing to yoursite.com, which will then do the contacting.

Comment: something like http://code.google.com/p/django-forms-builder/ or one of the million similar addins?

Comment: I believe that django-forms-builder could be useful. Although their forms would appear on their site so I would not be able to use the tags:

`{% render_build_form form_instance %}
{% render_build_form form=form_instance %}
{% render_build_form id=form_instance.id %}
{% render_build_form slug=form_instance.slug %}`

I am ok with not being able to do so I think this is what I want thanks!

Comment: @JoranBeasley you should put that in an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like http://code.google.com/p/django-forms-builder or one of the million similar addins?

(made into answer at OP's request)

Answer (score 0):

For this you would have some kind of editor that would create a html string. This string would be stored into your database and then upon request you would display it on the user's site.

The editor should be very strict into what it can add and what the user has control over, there are some javascript editors available that will be able to provide this functionality.

The only issue I can think of is that you may run into django escaping the form when displayed to the page.

Comment: What you are describing isn't what I want to do. If I wanted to do that I could use php and handle everything myself.

Comment: You would still need this as well, the user would create the form on your site and then the form would be displayed either through javascript adding the html to the page or through a iframe. This javascript/iframe code would then be given to the user to place on their site.

Comment: See the above comments. I will be able to handle the forms via django using http://code.google.com/p/django-forms-builder/.